# Is there any known explicit value of dimension of space of Maass forms?

Tags: number-theory, automorphic-forms

It is known that there exists a simple formula of the dimension of space of (holomorphic) modular forms on $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ in terms of its weight. Also, we have similar but rather complicated formula for the case of congruence subgroups. (I heard that there is an algorithm that computes these dimensions, right?)

However, we don't know much about dimension of Maass forms. As I know, it is widely conjectured that dimension of the space of Maass cusp forms on $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ with given eigenvalue is 0 or 1. Also, as we can see in [this post and answers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/102624/multiplicity-one-conjecture), it seems that there are some known upper bounds of dimension of level $q$ Maass wave forms in terms of $q$. 
Is there any concrete example that computes the exact value of dimensions?

Comment: The $L$-functions and modular forms database has computational examples of Maass forms, most of which occur with multiplicity one. But in general, it is extremely hard to bound the dimension of an eigenspace.

Comment: @PeterHumphries I just checked it, and I saw that there aren't any Maass forms with eigenvalue 1/4 (corresponds to $R=0$), but there exists an explicit example of such form (with a nontrivial multiplier system) by Cohen. Actually, I'm interested in Maass forms which has algebraic coefficients, and it seems that there's no such example in LMFDB.

Comment: Oh, you want Maass forms with eigenvalue 1/4 (or even two-dimensional Artin representations). I'm not sure these are implemented in the LMFDB yet. In this case, I imagine you can bound the dimension of the eigenspace via the method of Duke/Venkatesh.

Comment: @PeterHumphries Could you elaborate more? Which paper I can see?

Comment: Duke's IMRN paper on the dimension of the space of cusp forms of weight one. I think similar methods might work to bound the dimension (in terms of the congruence subgroup) of the space of weight zero Maass forms with eigenvalue $1/4$.

Comment: In any case, Maass forms with eigenvalue $\neq 1/4$ are conjectured to have transcendental Hecke eigenvalues. Those with eigenvalue $1/4$ are conjectured to correspond to even two-dimensional Artin representations and have algebraic Hecke eigenvalues.

Comment: @PeterHumphries I found it, thank you very much!